# How to get Nomenclature in table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, nomenclature

Can anyone advise me how to include the Nomenclature in the table of Contents as a seperate section. Like for example I want to have the Nomenclature in between List of Tables and the first chapter. I searched in Google. But all I was able to get is including a parameter in the preamble. Thanks for any help.

[image: Table of Contents]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This depends on how you generate your nomenclature list? With `nomencl`? With `glossaries`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question.

To get nomenclature in the Table of Contents the steps are as follows

1) Use `\usepackage[intoc, english]{nomencl}` under `\documentclass`

2) For Texusers>Options>Configure Texmaker> Under Make Index copy and paste this `makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg`. This step is very important

3) Include `\makenomenclature` before the `\begin {document}`

4) Also include `\printnomenclature` at the end

5) For including the nomenclature entries I would point to this guide [Nomenclature list entries](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Nomenclatures)

6) Next Click PDFLatex>MakeIndex and PDFLatex in this order only.

7) Voila! The Nomenclature entry displays now both in Table of Contents and the respective page.

Comment: I asked you whether you are using `nomencl` and you replied `no, I do it by hand`, now you're accepting a self-answer of something that was pretty clear in advance, if you would have posted a clear example....

Comment: I'm very new to Latex. So I googled myself and naturally stumbled across answers from other people on this forum. I did not know a thing before and at the beginning it was very confusing. When I did it myself, I posted an answer so that it could help others by the way instead of just deleting the question. :)

Comment: Old I know, but also simply adding \usepackage[intoc, english]{nomencl} before \usepackage{nomencl} may be enough for some users to just get the Nomencl. in your toc and hyperlinkable!